# Launching installer from C#

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have a winform application from which i'm running a separate bat file.
Once that bat file starts, it calls a setup.exe for the mysql desktop server engine. The setup.exe opens up and starts running, but only for like 1 second then it exits without any warning or error. The bat file continues to process the rest of the script.

Why is this happening? If i run the bat file separately (not from c#), it waits for the installation to be done and then proceeds with the script.

Thanks for the help

CODE ADDED:

```
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            if (File.Exists(@"C:\Program Files\Database setup\install.bat"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please restart the machine after installation is finished.");
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Database setup\install.bat";
                proc.Start();   

                //PROBLEM WITH INSTALLATION of SQLSERVER (INSTALL QUITS)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the batch script immediately after it runs the setup.exe process, add `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` to print out the return code. If you get something other than a 1 or 0, you could Google it.

Another thing to look for is whether it's got the same environment settings in both executions.
In the batch file, run `set` *before* starting setup.exe. that will print out all the environment settings. Compare the values you get running it manually vs from the C# process to see if any differences seem relevant.